# Structure with bit-fields size

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I tried to use a structure with different sized bit-fields. The total number of bits used is 64. However, when I check the structure size, I get **11** instead of an expected **8**. By trying to decompose the structure, I saw the difference came from the *day* field. If I pack every bit to get 8-bits packs, the *day* field is packed beetween the "end" of *month* and the "start" of *hour*. I don't know if this is a good approach. Can someone explain me that ?

```c
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

typedef struct frameHeader_t
    {
        uint8_t encryption       : 2;
        uint8_t frameVersion     : 2;
        uint8_t probeType        : 4;
        uint8_t dataType         : 5;
        uint8_t measurePeriod    : 3;
        uint8_t remontePerdiod   : 4;
        uint8_t nbrMeasure       : 2;
        uint8_t year             : 7;
        uint8_t month            : 4;
        uint8_t day              : 5;
        uint8_t hour             : 5;
        uint8_t minute           : 6;
        uint8_t second           : 6;
        uint8_t randomization    : 5;
        uint8_t status           : 4;

    }FrameHeader;

int main()
{

    FrameHeader my_frameHeader;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(FrameHeader));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need `#pragma pack` or similar (depending on your compiler, or more precisely, compiler's preprocessor). The `year` field "lands" on two bytes, so most likely it is padded by the compiler. Subsequently, some of the fields which follow it also "land" on two bytes, so more padding is applied.

Comment: The problem is this: "...an expected 8". There is no expected size of a bit-field. They can't be reliably used for memory-mapping.

Comment: In pure C, there's no guarantee about the memory layout of a struct.

Comment: In C, the traditional way to pack bit fields is to pack them inside integers whose size is the same as the declared integer type.  So in your example, they would be packed into 8-bit integers.  If a bit field didn't fit, it would skip to a new integer.  I believe the packing requirements have been loosened up since then, but it is still a common strategy.  So in your case the packings are (1) 2, 2, 4 (2) 5, 3 (3) 4, 2 (4) 7 (5) 4 (6) 5 (7) 5 (9) 6 (9) 6 (10) 5 (11) 4.  So you're ending up with 11 8-bit integers.  If you want improved packing, switch to a larger integer type, e.g. `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it through the `pahole` tool, you should get an explanation:

```
struct frameHeader_t {
    uint8_t                    encryption:2;         /*     0: 6  1 */
    uint8_t                    frameVersion:2;       /*     0: 4  1 */
    uint8_t                    probeType:4;          /*     0: 0  1 */
    uint8_t                    dataType:5;           /*     1: 3  1 */
    uint8_t                    measurePeriod:3;      /*     1: 0  1 */
    uint8_t                    remontePerdiod:4;     /*     2: 4  1 */
    uint8_t                    nbrMeasure:2;         /*     2: 2  1 */

    /* XXX 2 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    year:7;               /*     3: 1  1 */

    /* XXX 1 bit hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    month:4;              /*     4: 4  1 */

    /* XXX 4 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    day:5;                /*     5: 3  1 */

    /* XXX 3 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    hour:5;               /*     6: 3  1 */

    /* XXX 3 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    minute:6;             /*     7: 2  1 */

    /* XXX 2 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    second:6;             /*     8: 2  1 */

    /* XXX 2 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    randomization:5;      /*     9: 3  1 */

    /* XXX 3 bits hole, try to pack */

    uint8_t                    status:4;             /*    10: 4  1 */

    /* size: 11, cachelines: 1, members: 15 */
    /* bit holes: 8, sum bit holes: 20 bits */
    /* bit_padding: 4 bits */
    /* last cacheline: 11 bytes */
};
```

You're using `uint8_t` as the base type so the fields are getting padded to groups of 8 bits.

You should be able to completely eliminate the padding, somewhat more portably than with `__attribute((packed))` by using `unsigned long long`/`uint_least64_t` (at least 64 bits large) as the base type of the bitfields, but technically the non-int/non-unsigned-int base types for bitfields aren't guaranteed to be supported, but you could use `unsigned` (at least 16 bits guaranteed by the C standard) after reorganizing the bitfields a little, for example into:

```
typedef struct frameHeader_t
{
    //16
    unsigned year             : 7;
    unsigned randomization    : 5;
    unsigned month            : 4;

    //16
    unsigned second           : 6;
    unsigned minute           : 6;
    unsigned status           : 4;

    //16
    unsigned hour             : 5;
    unsigned dataType         : 5;
    unsigned probeType        : 4;
    unsigned encryption       : 2;

    //16
    unsigned day              : 5;
    unsigned remontePerdiod   : 4;
    unsigned measurePeriod    : 3;
    unsigned nbrMeasure       : 2;
    unsigned frameVersion     : 2;

}FrameHeader; 
//should be an unpadded 8 bytes as long as `unsigned` is 16,
//32, or 64 bits wide (I don't know of a platform where it isn't)
```

(The padding or lack thereof isn't guaranteed, but I've never seen an implementation insert it unless it was necessary.)

Comment: the problem with your solution is that it does not preserve the fields order making it useless when the received data fave its own order.

Comment: @P__J__ I do mention that using `unsigned long long`/`uint_least64_t` should fix it without the need to reorder.

Comment: @P__J__ For IO, I explicit bit manipulation from a `uin8_t` array should be the most portable approach.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the packing magic I usually use fixed size unsigned types with the same size

```
typedef struct frameHeader_t
    {
        uint64_t encryption       : 2;
        uint64_t frameVersion     : 2;
        uint64_t probeType        : 4;
        uint64_t dataType         : 5;
        uint64_t measurePeriod    : 3;
        uint64_t remontePerdiod   : 4;
        uint64_t nbrMeasure       : 2;
        uint64_t year             : 7;
        uint64_t month            : 4;
        uint64_t day              : 5;
        uint64_t hour             : 5;
        uint64_t minute           : 6;
        uint64_t second           : 6;
        uint64_t randomization    : 5;
        uint64_t status           : 4;

    }FrameHeader;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/BX2QsC